# How do you set the TDirect2DCanvas.Pen.StrokeStyle?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, direct2d, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I've been trying to modify the `StrokeStyle` for the `TDirect2DCanvas.Pen` in C++Builder.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Direct2D.TDirect2DPen.StrokeStyle) says this about the property:

> Determines the stroke style in which the pen draws lines.
>
> Use StrokeStyle to specify a more complex style in which the lines are drawn. StrokeStyle accepts an interface that provides a set of methods, each returning a certain drawing option.

The documentation gives no examples.  When I try to set this property to anything, I get a compile error saying "cannot write a property that has no write specifiers" (it looks like this property is only set up to read the StrokeStyle; even though the documentation seems to indicate otherwise).

My desire here is to get lines to be rendered with rounded ends rather than the flat ends that it seems to default to when using `TDirect2DCanvas`.  Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

I'm using C++Builder 10.2 and the clang compiler.  I'm trying to use `TDirect2DCanvas` rather than the regular `TCanvas` because it can draw anti-aliased lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is misleading.  The [`TDirect2DPen::StrokeStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Direct2D.TDirect2DPen.StrokeStyle) property is indeed read-only, as it represents the *current* Direct2D [`ID2D1StrokeStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1strokestyle) object, as created internally by `TDirect2DPen`.  `TDirect2DPen` does not provide *any* way to customize any of the stroke settings *other than* its `dashStyle`.

The only way to affect the `TDirect2DPen::StrokeStyle` is to set the [`TDirect2DPen::Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Direct2D.TDirect2DPen.Style) property.  Setting the `Style` will release the current `ID2D1StrokeStyle`, and then if the `Style` is set to a value *other than* `psSolid`, `psClear`, or `psInsideFrame` then `TDirect2DPen` will call [`ID2D1Factory::CreateStrokeStyle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1factory-createstrokestyle(constd2d1_stroke_style_properties__constfloat_uint32_id2d1strokestyle)) to create a new `ID2D1StrokeStyle`, specifying the following properties for it:

- startCap = D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT
- endCap = D2D1_CAP_STYLE_FLAT
- dashCap = D2D1_CAP_STYLE_ROUND
- lineJoin = D2D1_LINE_JOIN_ROUND
- miterLimit = 10
- dashStyle = one of the following, depending on the `TDirect2DPen.Style`:

  - D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH
  - D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DOT
  - D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH_DOT
  - D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH_DOT_DOT
- dashOffset = 0
- dashes = nil
- dashesCount = 0

This behavior is hard-coded and cannot be changed.

So, if you want more control over the `StrokeStyle`, you cannot use `TDirect2DCanvas` at all.  You will have to use the Direct2D API directly instead.

Comment: Thanks Remy, as usual your vast knowledge on all things VCL is greatly appreciated!  Thanks for sharing it with the community.

Comment: It was just a matter of looking at `TDirect2DPen`'s source code to see how the `StrokeStyle` property is being used.